# How to go to next line in file

Tags: c#

```
while (readIt.Peek() >= 0) {
    if (line.Contains("LogObjectUsage@1000000000 : Record 50000;")) {
        MessageBox.Show("Fajl ne treba da se menja");
        System.IO.File.Copy(txtb_Input_Folder.Text + Path.GetFileName(fileName), txtb_Output_folder.Text + Path.GetFileName(fileName), true);

    } else {
        line = readIt.ReadLine();
        if (line.Contains("PROPERTIES") && !line.Contains("OBJECT-PROPERTIES")) {
            sb.Append(line);
            nasao_prop = true;
        }.........
```

So the problem is when it finds"LogObjectUsage@1000000000 : Record 50000;" then I am in while loop, and I don't know how to go to the next line.

I am stuck in that line and I get infinitely TextBoxes. Can someone help me? How can I read in the next line after I found "LogObjectUsage@1000000000 : Record 50000;" line?

Comment: `readIt.ReadLine` reads the next line, from reading what you have here, I don't see why you are reading the same line over and over, unless there is another loop somewhere.

Comment: Correct. That is what I need. I solve the problem! Thank You,

Comment: Yes, I see the problem and I'm sure you found it, you aren't reading the next line inside the first part of the `if` statement, causing you not to read the next one if you find that line.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you want to first read a line, then inspect it. What you're doing is trying to read the line too late into the workflow.

```
while (readIt.Peek() >= 0)
{
    var line = readIt.ReadLine();
    if (line.Contains("LogObjectUsage@1000000000 : Record 50000;"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fajl ne treba da se menja");
        System.IO.File.Copy(txtb_Input_Folder.Text + Path.GetFileName(fileName), txtb_Output_folder.Text + Path.GetFileName(fileName), true);

    }
    else
    {
        if (line.Contains("PROPERTIES") && !line.Contains("OBJECT-PROPERTIES")) {
            sb.Append(line);
            nasao_prop = true;
        }
        .........
    }
    ...
}
```